# Facebook results into an NSArray

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I am using Facebook api to get user's friends name, UID and birthday. The problem I have is that how do I get to those values once I get the results back. Meaning, I want to get to username, birthdate for each returned value?

This code keeps crashing for me here

```
//set query
NSString *query =  @"SELECT uid, name, birthday_date FROM user WHERE uid IN " @"(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() LIMIT 25)";

// Set up the query parameter
NSDictionary *queryParam = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:query, @"q", nil];

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/fql"
                             parameters:queryParam
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        } 
    else {
        NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
        NSArray *friendInfo = (NSArray *) [result objectForKey:@"data"];
        NSArray *arryData3 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:friendInfo];
        NSLog(@"[friendInfo count]: %d ... [arryData3 count]: %d ...",[friendInfo count],[arryData3 count]);
        for (int i=0; i<[arryData3 count]; i++) {
            NSArray *bdayArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[arryData3 objectAtIndex:i]];
            //CODE CRASH HERE!!!!
            NSString *bdayStr = [bdayArray objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *nameStr = [bdayArray objectAtIndex:1];
        }
    }
}];
```

This is what my crash log looks like

```
data(
    {
        "birthday_date" = "01/06";
        name = "John Doe";
        uid = 555555;
    },
    {
        "birthday_date" = "09/01/1984";
        name = "Mrs. Smith";
        uid = 4444444;
    },
)
[friendInfo count]: 2 ... [arryData3 count]: 2 ...
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSArray initWithArray:range:copyItems:]: array argument is not an NSArray'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x168f052 0x1cabd0a 0x167fe0b 0x15e8170 0x16ca2 0x27c03 0x26c7e 0x2444e 0x2927e 0x296e7 0xfc1a59 0xfbfe94 0xfc0eb7 0xfbfe4f 0xfbffd5 0xf04f6a 0x3964bbd 0x3a315ea 0x395b298 0x3a3116b 0x395b137 0x166397f 0x15c6b73 0x15c6454 0x15c5db4 0x15c5ccb 0x3bd1879 0x3bd193e 0x5cca9b 0x2038 0x1f95)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that maybe interested in future. This is how you get to individual values in the results of Facebook.

```
NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
NSArray *friendInfo = (NSArray *) [result objectForKey:@"data"];
NSLog(@"[friendInfo count]: %d ....",[friendInfo count]);
for (int i=0; i<[friendInfo count]; i++)
{
    NSMutableString *userNameStr = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[friendInfo objectAtIndex:i]  objectForKey:@"name"]];
    NSMutableString *userDateStr = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[friendInfo objectAtIndex:i]  objectForKey:@"birthday_date"]];
    NSLog(@"userNameStr: %@ ... userDateStr: %@ ...", userNameStr,userDateStr);
   //From this point onwards you can put these individual strings into an array 
   //and if you had defined the array globally you can get to these results from 
   //any function in your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The return is a dictionary, not an array.
Please read about NSDictionary and use it just like you used the result - objectForKey function. In this case the key is birthday_date and then name for the strings in the for function.

Liviu